# scroll to elements up and down in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i want to do scroll to an element as whatsapp search

when user clicked `search (here it is bottom)` should scroll to last element

ie; element with id `chat-7`.
and when click `up button` should scroll to `chat-6` then `chat-5` ..and so on.

if click `down button` it should scroll to down if it is not last item.

```js
function scroll(id){
    console.log(id);
    $(".container").animate(
        { 
            scrollTop: $("#"+id).offset().top
        },
        "fast"
    );
}
```

full code here
http://jsfiddle.net/p3kar5bb/231/

unfortunately this code is not working properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your div `.container` doesn't have scroll bar so you can do two things.

**1. Animate Body**

```
$("body").animate({ scrollTop: $("#"+id).parent('.item').offset().top}, "fast");
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/p3kar5bb/232/)

**2. Set max-height to div**

```
.container{
   height: 100%;
   overflow-y: scroll;
   max-height:200px;    
  }
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/p3kar5bb/233/)

Comment: thats fine.butr when we click up more than once it is going to different position. for example when click up firt it should goto 6,then 5,..so on..but it is going to 2 after 6

Comment: @MohitKumar .thanks but this fiddle is not even scrolling.

Comment: is there any way to do this without giving min hieght to body?

Comment: what will happen if max-height is too big.?

Answer (score 0):

Perform the animate on the body instead of the .container

```
function scroll(id){
console.log(id);
$("body").animate({ scrollTop: $("#"+id).offset().top}, "fast");

}
```

Also set the

```
var pointedPosition=0;
```

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/p3kar5bb/234/

Comment: What is not Working? It Works fine for me. It does scroll to the respective Div. Can you check again?

Comment: this fiddle not  scrolling to element

Answer (score 0):

```
$('html, body').animate({
scrollTop: $("#"+id).offset().top
}, 500);
```

Code that is given in http://jsfiddle.net/p3kar5bb/231/ is fine, just change the animate() as above.

Just tried – $('html') does not work in Chrome and $('body') does not work in Firefox, so $('html, body') is needed. And also calling .stop() is a good thing.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the element id from buttons click event , try to change the scroll function code to this:

```
 function scroll(id){
      $('html, body').animate({ 
      scrollTop: $("#"+id).offset().top
        }, 2000);
}
```

And I have update your code here http://jsfiddle.net/p3kar5bb/231/.